# Cannot use pages created on WP

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, pages, 404-error

I am quite new to WP and I have recently taken over a development project of a page that I really don't understand quite well due to the weird options that the previous developer took. Unfortunately I cannot ask the previous developer about this since he refuses to answer any calls or e-mails, so I hope to get some enlightenment here. Going straight to the question:

- For some reason, it is not possible to use pages created by usual WP method (Pages --> Create new). After I do that and then add the page on the main menu I will get a 404
- I have seen that the previous developer has added custom post types on the functions.php. I could very easily solve this problem by duplicating one of them but unfortunately it does not work.
- I wonder if for some reason the previous developer has blocked the usage of pages created via traditional Wp method (Pages --> Create new)?
- How can I solve this? All I want is to be able to create a page and add it to the menu.

Please do let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do pages work when using another theme? Did you try disabling plugins?

Comment: This question is to broad for any specific answer. You can try reinstalling WordPress. This will fix if there are any admin files missing.

Comment: If you cannot tell what is happening with the code in front of you, I'm not sure you we are going to be able to guess. That isn't snark, sincerely. It is just a fact. Your previous developer did something bizarre that you are going to have to root out (or pay someone to root out). After that, perhaps we can help.

Comment: I understand your answers and you are right. Still this question was needed for helping me taking a decision. The decision is taken, we are building the shop again from the ground, but this time with common technology and not weird customized stuff. I would like to express my appreciation to all of you!